# What is the French Canadian word for "Hoser"?

Tags: sens, traduction, anglais, argot, régionalismes

The Canadian [slang](https://books.google.com/books?id=0twBxkXe5DsC&lpg=PA20&vq=hoser&dq=Hoser%20Canadian%20slang&pg=PA20#v=onepage&q=hoser&f=false) word [*hoser*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/hoser?s=t), "[a term having spawned several popular false etymologies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoser)", meaning "a person who is considered unintelligent or uncouth, especially a beer-drinking man" (Dictionary.com), doesn't seem to be in English-French [dictionaries](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/rechercher?q=hoser&l=anglais-francais&culture=) even though it's a uniquely Canadian concept (the origin of which might have been a self-deprecating usage):

> A Canadian, esp a simple and durable northern type •Originated by
>   comedians Dave Thomas and Rick Moranis for the television skits called
>   ''The Great White North,'' where it was used by the mentally
>   challenged Mackenzie brothers: *unavailable to us hosers, but can be
>   bought down south/ unlike their hoser cousins* (1980s+ Canadian)
>   ([Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/hoser?s=t)).

More or less adapted solutions may [exist](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/hoser.774481/), but what word/expression (including slang) is normally used by French Canadians to mean just that?

Comment: Here is a link with a quite relevant discussion about this translation, I hope you will find what you're looking for :
https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/hoser.774481/

Comment: Apparently, "hoser" isn't even used by Canadians, it's a word used to *imitate* Canadians, why would there be word in Canadian French ?

Comment: @TeleportingGoat Apparemment. L'article Wikipédia commence avec cette affirmation que vous faites, liée à la note 1. La note 1 renvoie à [ceci](https://books.google.ca/books?id=0twBxkXe5DsC&lpg=PA20&vq=hoser&dq=Hoser%20Canadian%20slang&pg=PA20#v=onepage&q=hoser&f=false), où on ne mentionne aucunement que c'est utilisé surtout par ceux qui imiteraient des Canadiens, on y dit plutôt que c'est du _slang_ canadien, au même titre que _ski-doo_, _toque_ ou _Newfie_. Toute information qui provient d'un truc qui débute par le mot _wiki_ doit faire l'objet d'une validation, incluant des références...

Comment: I'm sitting next to a Canadian at work, and a Canadian who plays hockey (where supposedly _hoser_ comes from). He said he never heard that word.

Comment: As a Canadian, I'll add that though I've encountered the word now and then, I've never used it myself, or heard it used, unironically -- that is, to talk "how Americans think we talk" (a frequent source of amusement up here).

Comment: Ça semble être un genre de "redneck" canadien, non ? Le "beauf" de chez nous.

Answer (score 2):

In french we have two or three words similar, with slightly different meanings (in my region of France).

***"Beauf"*** Describes someone shameless, mysoginist, who sometimes likes racist jokes, wears strange clothes and has a bad habit with alcool (particurlarly beer and pastis).

***"Poivreau"*** typically someone visiting the village pub everyday at any time and drinking waayy too much. We say "Le poivreau du village". He is not necessarily a loser and a stupid man, but he is known for being regurlarly drunk and behave like an asshole.

I think "Poivreau" fits perfectly here.

The meaning of a word or expression can be different between two regions of France.

Hope it helps !

Comment: Dans le même registre que "poivreau", il y a "pochtron" aussi.

Answer (score 1):

hoser in french is idiot for masculine or idiote for feminine. but idiot and idiote translate in to foolish person. I dont think there is a french Canadian word that means hoser i think this is as close to hoser as they have in the french Canadian language. i looked hoser up in a website called word reference.

Comment: "Hoser" contains three ideas:  "stupid" + "loser" + "beer-drinking", French *idiot* is far from a good translation. Using formatting and proper punctuation helps to readability of any written text. There are much better places than WordReference when looking for definitions or translations.

Answer (score 1):

'Beauf' seems to be the closest French equivalent.  Contemporary, short for 'beau-frere', an uncouth idiot you unfortunately have to put up with..

Comment: oh wait, there's an official definition.. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beauf

Comment: -1. Beauf is clearly French French and question is Canadian French.